# How can I fetch some block explorer data from blockchain.info?

Tags: javascript, jsonp, blockchain, bitcoin

I was wondering if somebody could give me some guidance. I am trying to get blockchain.info server answers me back with the current block number and the hash of it but honestly I have no idea how to do it. I wanted to do it using html & javascript and I was reading that I have to use JSONP or CORS for it to work but I still don't have an idea of how to make it work. If you could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check this link:

https://blockchain.info/latestblock

for further api:
https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api

I wrote a small widget for my desktop that just calls one of this urls and used regexp, to get what I want.